# Decode base64 to string and Encode string to base64 in XQuery

Tags: base64, xquery

I needed to work with base64 in Xquery on a project and found almost nothing on Internet, thankfully there was one GitHub repository that had what I need to complete the encode-decode.
So, if you have a xs:string and you need to encode as base64 or you have a base64 string and need to decode as xs:string* you can use the XQuery on the repository that is **highlighted as answer**. 
Obs: Comments are PT-BR, maybe you need to translate to understand what each function is used for

Comment: The link to the repo is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If your system supports it, use the EXPath binary library. Specification is at https://www.w3.org/2013/12/expath-binary-20131203/

See in particular the functions `bin:encode-string($string, $encoding)` which converts `xs:string` to `xs:base64Binary`, and `bin:decode-string($in, $encoding)` which converts `xs:base64Binary` to `xs:string`.

Answer (score 0):

Your XQuery context also might come with a utility function that does the conversion.
eXist-db offers `util:base64-encode` and `util:base64-decode`.